# Using humbleDB together with Django while reusing connections

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo

I want to use HumbleDB (https://humbledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in conjunction with Django. In my Django view I got something like that:

```
from humbledb import Mongo, Document

class HumbleDoc(Document):
    config_database = 'humble'
    config_collection = 'examples'
    description = 'd'
    value = 'v'

def index(request):
    with Mongo:
        HumbleDoc.insert(doc)
```

But this leads to a new MongoDB connection with every new web-request. How can I activate the connection pool, so connections actually get reused instead of spawned again on each request?

Thanks in advance for your help!